# How can the normal to a plane be used to calculate the distance to the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got quite a specific example with it's answer which I do not understand.

$M$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the equation:

($M$) $x + y + z = 0$

Let  ***x*** = [2,1,-2]. Calculate the distance $d$ of ***x*** from the plane $M$.

***m*** is the normal to the plane so ***m*** = [1,1,1,]

[The following photo is the given solution where they are using the normal to the plane to calculate the distance to the plane from **$x$**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuuJC.jpg)

If someone could explain the logic behind this calculation that would be great!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'd advise drawing a diagram. You'll see that the path of the shortest distance between a point and plane will be perpendicular to the plane. Hence you're interested in the normal. If you then try to find the answer from first principles, you should arrive at the same formula.

Comment: better way is to calculate the Hessian Normalform of the given plane

Comment: Which part is it you don't understand? Is it $d = \|\operatorname{Proj}_{\mathbf m}(\mathbf x)\|$? Is it $\|\operatorname{Proj}_{\mathbf m}(\mathbf x)\| = \frac{|\mathbf m\cdot [2, 1, -2]|}{\|\mathbf m\|}$? Or is it $ \frac{|\mathbf m\cdot [2, 1, -2]|}{\|\mathbf m\|} = \frac1{\sqrt3}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ be the point you call $\mathbf{x}$.  The general idea is that you can pick any point $Q$ in the plane (in your example they pick $Q=(0,0,0)$) and compute the vector $\mathbf{v}$ from $P$ to $Q$.  Vectors don't have location, so you can move the normal vector around so that its base is at $Q$.  If you draw this, it should be obvious that the distance from $P$ to the plane is the (scalar) projection of $\mathbf{v}$ onto the normal vector.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest path from the point $x$ to the plane is the one that "hits" the plane at a right angle (you can see this by using Pythagoras theorem). Now, the vector that goes in the direction perpendicular to the plane is precisely the normal vector $m$. So if you look at the projection of the vector pointing from any point of the plane to the point $x$ in the direction of the normal vector, you get the shortest possible path and hence the distance.

Now since the origin $O$ is an element of your plane, you can take the vector pointing from $O$ to $x$ which has exactly the same components as thr coordinates of $x$, i.e. $\vec{Ox} = (2,1,-2)$.

What is the projection of a vector $v$ onto another vector $u$? This is given by the scalar product with the normalised vector $u / \Vert u \Vert$, i.e. $\frac{1}{\| u \|}\langle v, u \rangle$. Apply this to $u = m$ and $v = \vec{Ox}$ and the final result is the formula of the photo.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi$ be the plane in question and $N$ its normal vector.

Let's say, we need to calculate the distance between a point $P$ and the plane $\pi$. Of course, we assume that $P\not\in \pi$

One way to do this is as follows: choose one point that is in the plane $\pi$, say, $Q$. And then we build the vector $\overrightarrow{PQ}$.

Of course, this vector has no reason to give us the distance between $P$ and $\pi$. But, if we consider $W$ as the orthogonal projection of $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ over $N$, what we obtain is that $W$ is parallel to $N$ and, if the final extreme of $W$ is set to be $P$, then the initial extreme of $W$ rests exactly on $\pi$.

Therefore, we may take $\Vert W \Vert$ (the norm of the orthogonal projection of $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ over the normal), as the distance between $P$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The normal vector $\mathbf{m}$ has a magnitude of $\sqrt{3}$. We can obtain a vector that is both normal to the plane and that has unit length as

$$
\hat{u} = \frac{\mathbf{m}}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

The plane contains the origin, now imaging a copy of $\hat{u}$ starting at the origin, the distance we want is the projection of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ onto the line that goes through $\hat{u}$. As $\hat{u}$ is a unit vector, we can simply take the dot product of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\hat{u}$

$$
\hat{u} \cdot \mathbf{x}
$$

to get our distance (the magnitude to be more precise). This is the same as the given solution.